# Is it possible to call a method on all generic properties in a class?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, covariance

I have a class with a lot of properties of type `IDbSet<SomeClass>`:

```
public InMemoryContext : IContext
{
    public IDbSet<ClassA> ClassASet { get; set; }
    public IDbSet<ClassB> ClassBSet { get; set; }
    [...]

    public void SaveChanges()
    {
        //TODO: this is relevant part
    }
}
```

All these properties are instantiated in the constructor:

```
public InMemoryContext
{
    ClassASet = new InMemoryDbSet<ClassA>();
    [...]
}
```

`InMemoryDbSet` has one relevant method for this question:

```
public class InMemoryDbSet<T> : IDbSet<T> where T : class
{
    public void SaveChanges()
    {
         [...]
    }
}
```

I'd like to get all properties that are `IDbSet` and call `SaveChanges()` on them in a loop, so I don't need to repeat all set names second time.

I tried with reflection but as my properties are generic I can't get it to work. I tried making `ClassA` and `ClassB` deriving from same common interface but still no luck.

Is it actually possible to do it without explicitly specifying all sets? What should I change to achieve this result?

I imagine the pseudocode to be like:

```
public void SaveChanges()
{
    foreach(var set in GetDbSetsFromClass(this))
    {
        set.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

With reflection I tried:

```
public void SaveChanges()
    {
        SaveChangesCalled = true;

        var properties = GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType.IsInterface && typeof(IDbSet<IEntity>).IsAssignableFrom(p.PropertyType)).Cast<InMemoryDbSet<IEntity>>();

        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            CallSaveChanges(property);
        }
    }
```

And the list is empty
        public bool SaveChangesCalled { get; set; }

```
    private static void CallSaveChanges<T>(InMemoryDbSet<T> set) where T : class
    {
        set.SaveChanges();
    }
```

EDIT: The public properties must remain visible at the top level of `InMemoryContext` class as this is restricted by the interface defining EF context.

Comment: "I tried with reflection" - reflection should work, what did you try?

Comment: Do the set have `SaveChanges` method? I can't find it in docs? What is that `IDbSet<T>` post the interface definition.

Comment: `InMemoryDbSet` has as it is shown in code. `IDbSet` doesn't. This is the hard part I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because `IDbSet<Class>` is not assignable to `IDbSet<IEntity>`, because `IDbSet<T>` is not covariant.

What you want is to find properties whose type's generic *definition* is `IDbSet<>`.

```
var properties = typeof (InMemoryContext)
    .GetProperties()
    .Where(p => p.PropertyType.IsGenericType &&
                p.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof (IDbSet<>));
```

To invoke your `CallSaveChanges` method, you'll need this:

```
foreach(var proparty in properties)
{
    var value = property.GetValue(this);
    var entityType = property.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments().First();

    var callSaveChanges = this.GetType()
                              .GetMethod("CallSaveChanges", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);

    var constructedCallSaveChanges = callSaveChanges.MakeGenericMethod(entityType );

    constructedCallSaveChanges.Invoke(null, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static, null, new object[]{ value }, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

That being said, I don't think this scenario warrants the usage of reflection.

Comment: I'm not limiting myself to reflection. If there's a better way I can take it.

Comment: I tried your solution and it is finding properties, but how can I call `SaveChanges()` on them? Casting to `InMemoryDbSet<IEntity>` doesn't work (in fact I would rather not use `IEntity` at all if possible). The method `SaveChanges()` is defined on `InMemoryDbSet` regardless of it's generic type after all.

Comment: @Episodex Oh, so there is a non-generic `InMemoryDbSet`? Just cast `values` to `InMemoryDbSet` then, that should work.

Comment: No, sorry for confusing you, `InMemoryDbSet` is generic (with definition like in question), but I think I shouldn't care what's the type of `T` if I want to just call SaveChanges() on it. Something like `IDbSet<>` but it can't be used in casting.

Comment: @Episodex Unfortunately, you'll have to jump through hoops to make this work. I've updated my answer.

Comment: That's perfectly fine for me, thanks! This is needed for my unit tests to have the context definition DRY and still capable of simulating `SaveChanges()` method from EF. Even if this means a couple of magic strings and some reflection - it's ok, it's not production code, and it will provide huge value for tests.

Comment: It is also possible to call `SaveChanges()` on set directly in the `foreach` loop: `property.GetType().GetMethod("SaveChanges", new Type[] {}).Invoke(property, null);`

Answer (score 1):

For a simple solution you could try something like this

```
public InMemoryContext
{
    public Dictionary<string, object> allSets = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    public InMemoryContext()
    {
        allSets.Add("classA", new InMemoryDbSet<ClassA>());
        allSets.Add("classB", new InMemoryDbSet<ClassB>());
        [...]
    }
    public IDbSet<ClassA> ClassASet { get
    {
        return allSets["classA"];
    }
    set
    {
        allSets["classA"] = Value
    }
    }
    [...]

    public void SaveChanges()
    {
    //TODO: this is relevant part
    foreach(var kvp in allSets)
    {
        kvp.Value.SaveChanges();
    }
    }
}
```

Some things maybe wrong since it's just off top of my head.. but you should get the idea

Comment: I also thought about this, but as this is `InMemoryContext` it must look exactly like EF context (it must fulfill some interface). I haven't put this explicit in question to not add more confusion, sorry.